# Radon Measures vs Sigma-Finitiness

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is every radon measure $\ \sigma$-finite?

*Let $\ (X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, where $\ X$ is a topological space. $\ \mu$ is a **Radon measure** if $\mu(K)<+\infty$ for each compact set $\ K\subseteq X$.*

*Let $\ (X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. $\ \mu$ is **$\ \sigma$-finite** if $\ \exists (V_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ such that $\ X=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}V_i$ and $\ \mu(V_i)<+\infty$ for every $\ i\in \mathbb{N}$.*

Answer (score 5):

Try an uncountable discrete space.  Then all compact sets are finite.  Let $\mu$ be counting measure.

Comment: This measure is also inner regular with respect to compact sets, which is sometimes a part of the definition of a Radon measure. (For instance, it is included in the definition on Wikipedia.) You can also take $\mu$ to be the counting measure on a Bernstein set on the real line (with Euclidean topology).

Comment: If I require $\ X$ to be a locally compact and separable metric space?

Comment: @avati91  If $X$ is a locally compact and separable metric space, then $X$ can be covered by a countable family of compact subsets, and then any Radon measure on $X$ must be $\sigma$-finite.